# Ajax.BeginForm OnSuccess based on input action

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

I am using Ajax.BeginForm with success in ASP.NET MVC with input type of different action as below code. I would like the OnSuccess to trigger based on the switch value (whether I click on the Save button or Delete button) but i do not know how can this be done or is there any alternative way? I would not like to have separate controller for this.

i.e.

```
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Save" />
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Delete" />
```

Then, in the controller I use

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id, string action)
{
   switch(action)
   {
      case "Save":
            ...
      case "Delete":
            ...
   }
}
```

Comment: I think you would find this far easier if your view contained 2 forms, one containing the controls for editing and the Save button that posts back to an `Edit(YourModel model)` method, and the other just containing a delete button that posts back to a `Delete(int ID)` method

Comment: i was trying to avoid using that way

Comment: are there no other solution?